# How to initialize a BitArray from a byte

Tags: c#, byte, bit, bitarray

In C#

```
BitArray ba = new BitArray((byte)70);
```

I expect that `ba` should be equal to `{0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0}`.
Instead I get a bunch of zero, (sorry did not count them I will post back if I need to).

I have searched a lot and I am frustrated. This should be an easy answer but I cannot seem to get a sensible easy answer. Many examples going the other way. What is the simplest way to get from `(byte)70` to bits `{01110000}`.
Thank you.

Comment: Read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=net-7.0): you're specifying a _size_ of 70, not passing the data of `70`.

Comment: Isn't `70` in binary form `1000110`?

Comment: 70 hex -- that might be my problem, is Byte var expressed in hex ?

Comment: Thanks, Coming from vb to c# still working on some of the concepts. This might be my answer. looking through my code.